# Converting string with US date and time format to UK format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have an application that stores date and time in a string field in an SQL Server 2008 table.

The application stores the date and time according to the regional settings of the PC that is running and we can’t change this behavior.

The problem is that some PCs have to be in UK date format with 12h time (eg. 22/10/2011 1:22:35 pm) some with UK date format with 24h time (eg. 22/10/2011 13:22:25) and some have to be US date format (eg. 10/22/2011 1:22:35 pm) and (eg. 10/22/2011 13:22:25).

**Is there any automatic way to change the string every time it changing/added to the table to UK 24h format so it will be always the same format in the database?**

**Can it be done using some trigger on update or insert? Is there any built-in function that already does that?**

Even a script to run it from time to time may be do the job...
I’m thinking to break apart the string to day, month , year, hour, minute, second , AM/PM and then put the day and month part in `dd/mm` order and somehow change the hour part to 24h if PM, get rid of the “am” and “pm” and then put the modified date/time back to the table.

For example the table has

```
id datestring              value           Location   
1  15/10/2011 11:55:01 pm  BLAHBLAH        UK
2  15/10/2011 13:12:20     BLAKBLAK        GR
3  10/15/2011 6:00:01 pm   SOMESTUFF       US
4  10/15/2011 20:16:43     SOMEOTHERSTUFF  US
```

and we want it to be

```
id datestring           value              Location
1  15/10/2011 23:55:01  BLAHBLAH           UK
2  15/10/2011 13:12:20  BLAKBLAK           GR
3  15/10/2011 18:00:01  SOMESTUFF          US
4  15/10/2011 20:16:43  SOMEOTHERSTUFF     US
```

We can display the date parts (day,month,year) correctly using the datepart function but with the time part we have problems because it changes too many ways.

**Edited to explain some more**

mr. p.campbell thanks for the edit .. i didn't know how to beautify it :)

and mr. Matthew, thank you for your quick reply..

We can tell if it is UK date or US date because we have another field i didn't mention with the text "US", "UK", "GR", "IT" according to where the PLC machine is located.

I'm sorry i didn't explain it to well. My english are not so good.

There are two different and independent applications. And they don't have direct relation with the sql server.

The application that only writes data to the database ..lets call it "the writer" for short.. and a different application that reads the data .. lets call it "the reader".

"The writer" is an internal application of a PLC machine that stores values every 1 min to the database that's why we can't change its behavior. It uses the string data type to store the date and the time at the same field according to the regional settings of the pc that a daemon application runs and does the communication between the pc and the PLC machine.

Now "the reader" expects the date and time to be in the format "dd/mm/yyyy 23:23:01" or "yyyy/mm/dd 23:23:01" and the only thing it does for now is doing some calculations with the data in the value field between given dates. eg. from 10/09/2011 10:00:00 to 15/09/2011 14:00:00.

we just need to do something like this ...

select * from table1 where datestring between "10/09/2011 10:00:00" and "15/09/2011 14:00:00"

I could post some of the code but it will be very long post.

Comment: If you are looking at scripts/triggers etc can you add a date field to the schema and make the script update that (obviously the best fix is to use the correct type in the db)

Comment: Hello Mark.. do you mean to put a trigger when the datestring updates to put to other field new date time? i had think of that but the date and time that the application stores is not the current date time of the sql server.

Comment: You need to convert this to a datetime column rather than a string column. It's the only real solution.

Answer (score 4):

At first, I agreed with Matthew, but then I realized that, given the information presented, this actually *was* possible (well, sorta).

However, some caveats;

1. You are doing nobody *any* favors by storing and maintaining the database this way.  Your best bet is to change the application to have it give an actual `Datetime` value, not this mangled string.
2. This data ***CANNOT*** be meaningfully sorted by date or time (not without performing expensive string manipulation).
3. You appear to be storing all times as *local* times, but do not appear to be storing a `TimeZone` or related information.  Without this information,  you will ***NOT*** be able to (completely) correctly translate times 'globally'.  For instance, which is later - 4PM in London, or 11AM in New York (for, say, an international conference call)? The answer is that *you don't know*: it depends on the time of year.
4. You are storing local times, period.  This only works *so long as* local time is correct.  What happens when somebody sets their clock to 1900?  You should be storing time based off of the ***SERVER'S*** clock.
5. Your stored timestamp is based on a formatted string.  If the user changes how their time is displayed, your data correctness (potentially) goes out the window.  For instance, what if somebody removes the am/pm symbols, thinking "I'll look out the window - if the sun is out, it's 'am'"?

Please keep all of that in mind.

---

As to how to do this....
I'm not going to actually write out the SQL statement for this.  Mostly because storing the information this way is pretty terrible.  But also because it's going to take a lot of work I'd rather not do.  I *really* recommend stressing to whomever has the keys at your place to get that application changed.

So instead, I'm going to give you a really big clue - and this will only work for so long as your timestamp format remains the same; You *should* be able to tell what format the date and time are in based on the presence and absence of 'am' and 'pm' in the string (if you don't have both, you're flat-out toast).  As Matthew has pointed out, the formatting is also likely different for the **date**, as well as the time - you will need to translate both.  However, this will *immediately* give you problems due to comparative timestamps (please see point 4, above); any attempt to run scheduling or auditing with this data id pretty much doomed to failure ("When did that happen?" "Well, it's in the UK date format, so..." "But that makes it 1AM here, and he was dead then!").

## Most beneficial answer: Change how the information is stored in the database

---

**EDIT:**

And then it hits me (especially in light of the new edits) - there are potentially other possibilities that could actually make this work....

First, change your database to actually store some sort of 'globalized' timestamp, based off of the server's clock.
This will of course break your existing application code - it would get a data-type mismatch error.  To fix that, rename the table, then create a view, named the same as the original table, that will return the string formatted as indicated in the 'source' column.  You'll need to create `instead-of` triggers for the view, to translate the formatted string to an actual `datetime` value.  The best part is, *the application code should never notice the difference*.  You seem to have indicated that you have sufficient control over the database to allow this to happen; this should allow you to 'fix' the data transparently.

This of course works best if the incoming datetime values are absolute (not local).  Hopefully, the values are actually supposed to be 'insert time' - these could likely be safely ignored, in favor of using a special register (like `NOW` or `CURRENT DATE` or whatever).

Can't believe this didn't hit me earlier...

Comment: You both are completely right to your thoughts .. i already pointed the problem to the company that produces the PLC machines ..(is a well known german company i can't say the name but i believe some of you have cell phones, call centers and other equipment from there)

Comment: .. and the answer was that this is the way their machines works and it can't be changed. The only thing I can do now is to change the regional settings to every pc that is between the PCL and the database and lock it somehow the regional settings to yyyy/mm/dd and 24h time. But I will need some way to change and normalize the data I have already in the database. And they are more than 5.000 entries to 5 tables.

Comment: @X-Zero if he can change how the machines report then he should just store UTCTime or some other standardized date and process it on the client. This whole problem is because he can't change the client.

Comment: @MatthewPK I completely agree.

Answer (score 2):

You stated that you cannot change the application behavior, thus **this is not possible**.

Your problem is that your database doesn't know the culture / timezone settings of the client and your client doesn't report it.

You will need to report this data or think of clever ways to *infer* this information before you can act on it.

**EDIT:** For example, without knowledge of the client's details how could you tell the difference between the strings:
`10/1/2011 12:00:00` (October First, noon, US)
`10/1/2011 12:00:00` (January Tenth, noon, UK)

?